# Why after each build something inject <script> tags in index.cshtml form wwwroot (Angular 6 CLI AspNet Core)

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, angular-cli, angular6

I use only ng build (static files) in wwwroot which are used by an aspnet core app.

this is index.cshtml from my project:

[image]

this is the code after I ran: `ng build` and I start my project

[image]

Somehow it puts that scripts before page and I don't know why, because I already put there.

I only create an asp net core project MVC and after that with CLI I create an empty project in a subfolder, outputPath from angular.json is modified to point in wwwroot in a new folder

I only use ng build and project use those static files from wwwroot

Comment: post the screenshot instead of link?

Comment: don't use ng-build. When you create Angular 6 project. The 2.1 Angular templates comes with Angular Cli middleware. Once your application start, all the ts/angular/javascript/css files will be complied and bundled and served when your application is loaded in the browser. Otherwise use a simple index.html (not cshtml, this rare razor views/pages)

Comment: All you have to do is run the application with F5, rest ASP.NET Core should do for you.

Comment: @Ringo I can't post screenshot because throw me an error